# How does Imprinting and the affinity work together?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm currently working on a artifact deck (casual). I am thinking of imprinting [Somber Hoverguard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Somber%20Hoverguard) on [Soul Foundry](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20Foundry). But how do I dertermine the imprint cost, and will the activation cost of Soul Foundry change as the numbers of artifacts change on my battlefield?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't get any benefits from Affinity.

---

The activation cost of Soul Foundry's activated ability is based on the Converted Mana Cost (CMC) of the imprinted card, and Somber Hoverguard's CMC is 6.

> 202.3. The converted mana cost of an object is a number equal to the total amount of mana in its mana cost, regardless of color.
>
> 202.1. A card’s mana cost is indicated by mana symbols near the top of the card. [...]

Affinity doesn't affect the mana cost. It's a cost reduction that reduces the cost to cast the spell, not its mana cost. To paraphrase 601.2e,

> cost to cast a spell
>   = mana cost or alternative cost
>   + additional costs and cost increases
>   - cost reductions